# "BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash: invalid hash" when trying to authenticate password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passwords, bcrypt

I have a model `User`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
end
```

I'm using `gem 'bcrypt', '3.1.11'`. But for some reason the `authenticate` method doesn't work.

I have a User record `user` where `user.password_digest == "password"`. But typing in `user.authenticate('password')` in console returns the following error:

```
> user.authenticate('password')
BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash: invalid hash
from /home/.rvm/gems/bcrypt-3.1.11/lib/bcrypt/password.rb:60:in 'initialize'
```

I don't even think the argument is supposed to be a hash: isn't it just supposed to be a string? What's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a `Hash` object, it refers to the [hash value](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function#Password_verification) in `password_digest` which seems to be invalid, that is, you set it incorrectly.

Try this:

```
user.password = 'password'
user.password_confirmation = 'password'
user.save
```

Now you can authenticate with:

```
user.authenticate('password')
```